# Finding particular solution of recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve recurrence relation problem -

$a_r - 3a_{r-1} + 3a_{r-2} + a_{r-3} = 4.$

So far I simplified it to $a_3 - 3a_2 + 3a - 3 = 0.$

Then, $a_2(a-3) + 3(a-1) = 0.$

But it seems I am going wrong somewhere. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: The first two equations are unrelated.

Comment: Please fix the typo.

Comment: Hey..sorry but thats how my textbook show to simplify the recurrence problem. Someone from stackoverflow gave me a hint about homogenous and non-homogenous but I couldn't implement it. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002443/finding-particular-solution-of-recurrence-relation

Comment: where's the typo?

Comment: There is a sign error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a constant solution $c$, we have

$$c-3c+3c+c=4.$$